# AsyncStorage retuning null not get Item

Tags: react-native

asyncStorage getItem. the console is showing the value is null . how to solve this ?

```
 async componentWillMount(){
   await AsyncStorage.setItem("user", {"name": "nahid" , "id": "2323"})

  }

  async componentDidMount() {
   var res = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
   console.log("sdds",res)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `value` as Object. Value must be string. You can use `JSON.Stringify(your object)` to store object

Answer (score 0):

i have found the answer.

```
 async componentWillMount(){


       await AsyncStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify({"name": "nahid" , "id": "2323"}))

      }

      async componentDidMount() {
       var res = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
       console.log("value",JSON.parse(res))
      }
```